# Lighttpd and sub directories

Tags: lighttpd

I have URL like :

```
http://example.com/dir1/...
http://example.com/dir2/...
http://example.com/dir3/...
```

and I would like to retrieve the **dir1**, **dir2**, **dir3**... (they are not real directories) in a DIR_NUMBER environment variable :

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/(.*)/" {
    setenv.add-environment = ( "DIR_NUMBER" => $1)

    url.rewrite-once = (
      "^/(.*)" => "/index.php/$1" 
    )
  }
```

It does not work, any idea ? Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `url.redirect` instead of `url.rewrite-once` if it's not a real file which the webserver is trying to access.